# ASP.NET Identity Role management through LDAP Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and have developed an MVC5 application. I had implemented the application to use LocalDB with ASP.NET Identity for authentication and authorization. I have now changed it to authenticate against LDAP which I have successfully implemented. Now I need to manage user roles still with identity but I cant seem to find any relevant code in the `IdentityModel.cs` nor the `AccountController` that can point me in the right direction on how to tweak my application to authenticate through LDAP and authorize through Identity.

Comment: hey man, do you mind to show me your code on how to authenticate against active directory? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314549/authenticate-user-through-active-directory-ldap-with-asp-identity

Answer (score 1):

> ...authenticate through LDAP and authorize through Identity.

I'm assuming this means storing roles somewhere else (in your localdb) while using LDAP for authorization. Without seeing your code to be sure, it sounds like the job is to add claims to filter after logging in from another provider.

Here's an approach for adding that to your LDAP login:

http://brockallen.com/2013/01/17/adding-custom-roles-to-windows-roles-in-asp-net-using-claims/

After that, you can use typical MVC `[Authorize(Roles="Administrator")]` filters on your controllers/actions to implement roles.

Answer (score 0):

Store the roles in LDAP as well - it's not rocket surgery and roles -> getmembers and user -> memberof... it'll work both ways. Just create a Container called "Roles". Then create "Groups" for each role in your app.. Add users as members of the group.. ---